# AmbiguousMatchException - Type.GetProperty - C# Reflection

Tags: c#

Yesterday I ran into an Issue while developing a Web Part (This question is not about webpart but about C#). Little background about the Issue. I have a code that load the WebPart  using the Reflection, In which I got the AmbiguousMatchException. To reproduce it try the below code

```
        public class TypeA
        {
            public virtual int Height { get; set; }
        }
        public class TypeB : TypeA
        {
            public String Height { get; set; }
        }
        public class Class1 : TypeB
        {

        }

        Assembly oAssemblyCurrent = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Type oType2 = oAssemblyCurrent.GetType("AmbigousMatchReflection.Class1");
        PropertyInfo oPropertyInfo2 = oType2.GetProperty("Height");//Throws AmbiguousMatchException 
        oPropertyInfo2 = oType2.GetProperty("Height", 
            BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);  // I tried this code Neither these BindingFlags or any other didnt help
```

I wanted to know the BindingFlag to Fetch the Height Property. You will have the question of why  I wanted to create another Height Property that is already there in the Base class. That is how the `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.PageViewerWebPart` was designed check the Height property of the PageViewerWebPart class.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two `Height` properties there, and *neither* of them are declared by Class1 which you're calling `GetProperty` on.

Now, would it be fair to say you're looking for "the Height property declared as far down the type hiearchy as possible"? If so, here's some code to find it:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;

public class TypeA
{
    public virtual int Height { get; set; }
}

public class TypeB : TypeA
{
    public new String Height { get; set; }
}

public class Class1 : TypeB
{        
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Type type = typeof(Class1);
        Console.WriteLine(GetLowestProperty(type, "Height").DeclaringType);
    }

    static PropertyInfo GetLowestProperty(Type type, string name)
    {
        while (type != null)
        {
            var property = type.GetProperty(name, BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | 
                                                  BindingFlags.Public |
                                                  BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (property != null)
            {
                return property;
            }
            type = type.BaseType;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note that if you *know* the return types will be different, it *may* be worth simplifying the code as shown in [sambo99's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994698/ambiguousmatchexception-type-getproperty-c-reflection/994717#994717). That would make it quite brittle though - changing the return type later could then cause bugs which would only be found at execution time. Ouch. I'd say that by the time you've done this you're in a brittle situation anyway :)

Comment: Well I did the same fix. I wanted to confirm its a Design issue with the class.The way in which I Designed the class is not right

Comment: @Jon, not exactly accurate see my answer

Comment: Which bit isn't accurate? I agree that kusek could specify the desired return type, but I don't think anything I've written is actually wrong, is it?

Comment: "There are two Height properties there, and neither of them are declared by Class1" is not accurate, the call to getproperty can resolve this situation fine see BarBar2 sample

Comment: Which bit are you disputing? There are clearly two different properties. Are you claiming they *are* declared by Class1? They're not, which is why you won't get either of them using DeclaredOnly in conjunction with Class1. One is declared by TypeA, and the other is declared by TypeB. Just because you can ask GetProperty to resolve it doesn't mean it's *declared* by Class1.

Comment: (i.e. your p example doesn't show fetching by declaration, and your p2 example shows fetching it by the declaration in Bar, not BarBar.)

Comment: @Jon yerp declardonly makes the call blind to all types in the hierarchy. all im saying is that a parameterless call to GetProperty will resolve fine up the hierarchy provided there is not Type clash. (Eg.  var p3 = typeof(BarBar2).GetProperty("Height"); works even though height is defined in Foo2 and Foo)

Comment: And that's fine - but it doesn't go against anything I said. In particular, the statement that "There are two Height properties there, and neither of them are declared by Class1" *is* accurate.

Comment: That's fine, just nitpicking, your answer covers all the aspects this question needs covered. A separate question on scenarios for overriding return types of properties should be asked, I am struggling to think up even one real world case.

Comment: I'm absolutely fine with nitpicking, I just dispute the nits in this particular case :)

Answer (score 4):

See the following example:

```
    class Foo {
        public float Height { get; set; }
    }

    class Bar : Foo {
        public int Height { get; set; }
    }

    class BarBar : Bar { }

    class Foo2 : Foo{
        public float Height { get; set; }
    }

    class BarBar2 : Foo2 { } 

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        // works 
        var p = typeof(BarBar).GetProperty("Height", typeof(float), Type.EmptyTypes);

        // works
        var p2 = typeof(BarBar).BaseType.GetProperty("Height", BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        // works
        var p3 = typeof(BarBar2).GetProperty("Height");

        // fails
        var p4 = typeof(BarBar).GetProperty("Height"); 

        Console.WriteLine(p);

    }
```

- You get an AmbiguousMatchException if a two or more properties with the **differing** return types and the **same name** live in your inheritance chain.
- Stuff resolves just fine if you override an implementation (using new or override) and maintain the return type.
- You can force reflection only to look at the properties for a particular type.

Comment: Well I did the same fix it. But is that a Design Issue ?

Comment: no, actually Tetraneutron has it right, this happens if you have two properties with the same Name that return different types, something that is pretty bad design anyway

Comment: To be honest, hiding a property is a design issue to start with. It's very likely to cause issues where you're *really* trying to call the base Height property. I'd strongly advise you not to do it if you can possibly avoid it. If you absolutely *have* to, then use the "new" modifier to make it clear at the declaration point.

Comment: Agreed, I have no idea why you would want to hide a property like this.

Comment: Agreed overriding a return type of a property is a very big no-no

Comment: Thinking about this further, I'm not sure that changing the return type is actually any worse than hiding the property using the *same* type. Arguably it's *better* - because in many situations if you accidentally refer to the wrong property, the compiler will catch it. The big problem is hiding a property to start with, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously there are two properties that match the name you have given of "Height", one with return type int, and another string.,  Just add the return type as the second parameter tot the GetPropertyCall depending on which you want returning and this ambiguity should disappear.

Comment: yeah I just tested this, you only get the ambiguous exception if two properties with the same name have different return types

Answer (score 2):

I created two extension methods extending on Jon Skeet's answer. You can place those in any public static class.

Edit: Removed the `MissingMemberException` to behave more like the default .NET implementations which return null on failure.

Usage:

```
var field = type.GetFieldUnambiguous(type, "FieldName", bindingFlags);
var property = type.GetPropertyUnambiguous(type, "PropertyName", bindingFlags);
```

Implementation:

```
public static FieldInfo GetFieldUnambiguous(this Type type, string name, BindingFlags flags)
{
    if (type == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
    if (name == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));

    flags |= BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;

    while (type != null)
    {
        var field = type.GetField(name, flags);

        if (field != null)
        {
            return field;
        }

        type = type.BaseType;
    }

    return null;
}

public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyUnambiguous(this Type type, string name, BindingFlags flags
{
    if (type == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
    if (name == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));

    flags |= BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;

    while (type != null)
    {
        var property = type.GetProperty(name, flags);

        if (property != null)
        {
            return property;
        }

        type = type.BaseType;
    }

    return null;
}
```