# Alternative pattern for new property (AmbiguousMatchException)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I use the following pattern to generically create specialized instances of a base view mdoel according to the concrete model instance:

```
#region Model

public class Model
{

}

public class DerivedModel : Model
{

}

#endregion

#region ViewModel

public abstract class ViewModel
{
    public static ViewModel Create(Model model)
    {
        return (ViewModel)CreateInternal((dynamic) model);
    }

    private static ViewModel<TModel> CreateInternal<TModel>(TModel model)
    {
        var viewModel = IoC.Get<ViewModel<DerivedModel>>();
        viewModel.Model = model;
        return viewModel;
    }

    public Model Model { get { return GetModel(); } }
    internal abstract Model GetModel();
}

public abstract class ViewModel<TModel> : ViewModel where TModel : Model
{
    public new TModel Model { get; internal set; }
    internal override Model GetModel() { return Model; }
}

[Export(typeof(ViewModel<DerivedModel>))]
/*private*/ class MySpecializedModel : ViewModel<DerivedModel>
{
    //specialization
}

#endregion
```

The idea is to instanciate them via MEF so there is no need to know the conrcete ViewModel Type, and the specializations can be defined in some other assemblies and plugged into the program at runtime.

However, I get an AmbiguousMatchException somewhere deep inside the wpf framework when trying to bind to the `Model` property (indeed, not the binding itself fails but some code in MeasureOverride tries to access the property via reflection):

```
System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException occurred
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
mscorlib.dll!System.RuntimeType.GetPropertyImpl(string name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Type returnType, System.Type[] types, System.Reflection.ParameterModifier[] modifiers) + 0x127 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Type.GetProperty(string name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags bindingAttr) + 0x1f bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.PropertyPath.GetPropertyHelper(System.Type ownerType, string propertyName) + 0x31 bytes    
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.PropertyPath.ResolvePropertyName(string name, object item, System.Type ownerType, object context, bool throwOnError) + 0x8e bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.GetInfo(int k, object item, ref MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.SourceValueState svs) + 0x3b5 bytes   
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.ReplaceItem(int k, object newO, object parent) + 0x302 bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(int k, System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView collectionView, object newValue, bool isASubPropertyChange) + 0xea bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.AttachDataItem() + 0x9e bytes   
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Activate(object item) + 0x10d bytes 
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.AttachToContext(System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.AttachAttempt attempt) + 0x33a bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.AttachOverride(System.Windows.DependencyObject target, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp) + 0xd1 bytes   
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.OnAttach(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp) + 0x38 bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetInstanceValue(System.Windows.UncommonField<System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary[]> dataField, System.Windows.DependencyObject container, System.Windows.FrameworkElement feChild, System.Windows.FrameworkContentElement fceChild, int childIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, int i, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry entry) + 0x1a5 bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetChildValueHelper(System.Windows.UncommonField<System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary[]> dataField, ref MS.Utility.ItemStructList<System.Windows.ChildValueLookup> valueLookupList, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.DependencyObject container, MS.Internal.FrameworkObject child, int childIndex, bool styleLookup, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry entry, out System.Windows.ValueLookupType sourceType, System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot) + 0x4e7 bytes   
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetChildValue(System.Windows.UncommonField<System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary[]> dataField, System.Windows.DependencyObject container, int childIndex, MS.Internal.FrameworkObject child, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, ref MS.Utility.FrugalStructList<System.Windows.ChildRecord> childRecordFromChildIndex, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry entry, out System.Windows.ValueLookupType sourceType, System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot) + 0xbc bytes 
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetValueFromTemplatedParent(System.Windows.DependencyObject container, int childIndex, MS.Internal.FrameworkObject child, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, ref MS.Utility.FrugalStructList<System.Windows.ChildRecord> childRecordFromChildIndex, System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry entry) + 0x52 bytes 
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplatedParentValue(System.Windows.DependencyObject container, MS.Internal.FrameworkObject child, int childIndex, ref MS.Utility.FrugalStructList<System.Windows.ChildRecord> childRecordFromChildIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot) + 0x78 bytes 
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StyleHelper.InvalidatePropertiesOnTemplateNode(System.Windows.DependencyObject container, MS.Internal.FrameworkObject child, int childIndex, ref MS.Utility.FrugalStructList<System.Windows.ChildRecord> childRecordFromChildIndex, bool isDetach, System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot) + 0x8c bytes   
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.InvalidatePropertiesOnTemplate(System.Windows.DependencyObject container, object currentObject) + 0xcf bytes 
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.HandleBeforeProperties(object createdObject, ref System.Windows.DependencyObject rootObject, System.Windows.DependencyObject container, System.Windows.FrameworkElement feContainer, System.Windows.Markup.INameScope nameScope) + 0x2d bytes    
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadOptimizedTemplateContent.AnonymousMethod__3(object sender, System.Xaml.XamlObjectEventArgs args) + 0x24 bytes    
System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.OnBeforeProperties(object value) + 0x46 bytes  
System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_CreateAndAssignToParentStart(MS.Internal.Xaml.Context.ObjectWriterContext ctx) + 0xfe bytes  
System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteEndObject() + 0x2ae bytes 
System.Xaml.dll!System.Xaml.XamlWriter.WriteNode(System.Xaml.XamlReader reader) + 0x65 bytes    
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(System.Xaml.XamlReader templateReader, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter currentWriter) + 0x41 bytes 
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter objectWriter) + 0x61 bytes 
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadOptimizedTemplateContent(System.Windows.DependencyObject container, System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector componentConnector, System.Windows.Markup.IStyleConnector styleConnector, System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.DependencyObject> affectedChildren, System.Windows.UncommonField<System.Collections.Hashtable> templatedNonFeChildrenField) + 0x259 bytes 
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadContent(System.Windows.DependencyObject container, System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.DependencyObject> affectedChildren) + 0x7b bytes   
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplateContent(System.Windows.UncommonField<System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary[]> dataField, System.Windows.DependencyObject container, System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot, int lastChildIndex, System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary childIndexFromChildID, System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate) + 0xa5 bytes    
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ApplyTemplateContent(System.Windows.UncommonField<System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary[]> templateDataField, System.Windows.FrameworkElement container) + 0x3b bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate() + 0x7c bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x40 bytes   
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x1cc bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size constraint) + 0x60 bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x1cc bytes  
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x1cc bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size constraint) + 0x281 bytes    
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x1cc bytes  
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x1cc bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(int cell, bool forceInfinityV) + 0xe9 bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(int cellsHead, System.Windows.Size referenceSize, bool ignoreDesiredSizeU, bool forceInfinityV, out bool hasDesiredSizeUChanged) + 0x8a bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size constraint) + 0x3e6 bytes    
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x1cc bytes  
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x1cc bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(int cell, bool forceInfinityV) + 0xe9 bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(int cellsHead, System.Windows.Size referenceSize, bool ignoreDesiredSizeU, bool forceInfinityV, out bool hasDesiredSizeUChanged) + 0x8a bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size constraint) + 0x3e6 bytes    
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x1cc bytes  
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size availableSize) + 0x1cc bytes  
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size constraint) + 0x60 bytes  >   Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation.dll!Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadTreeViewItem.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size availableSize) Line 1537 + 0x28 bytes

...
```

Therefore, the answer to use some user-defined function which searches the inheritance chain, e.g. as proposed in the thread [AmbiguousMatchException - Type.GetProperty - C# Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994698/ambiguousmatchexception-type-getproperty-c-sharp-reflection), does not apply here.

How could the pattern be alternatively implemented so that I can access the specialized `Model` property from inside the specialized viewmodel class, but also enable accessing the base property from the base viewmodel? Renaming the property looks ugly, as it points to the same object anyway!

Comment: This is a terrible idea... view models are not all the same. They are used to provide exactly the data and functionality required by each view. Your 'pattern' breaks this idea and therefore renders its use somewhat pointless.

Comment: Not all viewmodels are the same, but there can be multiple related viewmodels:
e.g.: i have list of different devices and want to generate a list of viewmodels to edit the specicfic parameters the specific device - how can I generate a viewmodel for the corresponding device - especially if there may be multiply devices which are not known at compile time?